# ActiveAdmin Dashboard partial not appearing?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, highcharts, partial-views, activeadmin

I'm trying to include a section containing a partial in my Dashboard on ActiveAdmin. The section appears, but it is blank - how do I make the partial appear? I want to display a Highcharts graph.

Here is my code:

dashboards.rb:

```
section "Business Summary", do
    div do
         render 'graph'

       end
  end
```

_graph.html.erb( located in app/views/admin/dashboard):

```
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
  $(function() {
    var chart;
    $(document).ready(function() {
        chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
            chart: {
                renderTo: 'container',
                type: 'column'
            },

            xAxis: {
                categories: ['Automotive', 'Agency', 'Contractor', 'Country Club', 'Other']
            },
            yAxis: {
                min: 0,

                title: {
                    text: 'Business Summary'
                },
                stackLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                    style: {
                        fontWeight: 'bold',
                        color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.textColor) || 'gray'
                    }
                }
            },
            legend: {
                align: 'right',
                x: 100,
                verticalAlign: 'top',
                y: 0,
                floating: true,
                backgroundColor: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.legendBackgroundColorSolid) || 'white',
                borderColor: '#CCC',
                borderWidth: 1,
                shadow: false
            },
            tooltip: {
                formatter: function() {
                    return '<b>' + this.x + '</b><br/>' + this.series.name + ': ' + this.y + '<br/>' + 'Total: ' + this.point.stackTotal;
                }
            },
            plotOptions: {
                column: {
                    stacking: 'normal',
                    dataLabels: {
                        enabled: true,
                        color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.dataLabelsColor) || 'white'
                    }
                }
            },
            series: [{
                name: 'Mobile',
                data: [5, 3, 4, 27, 2]},
            {
                name: 'Foursquare',
                data: [2, 2, 3, 2, 1]},
            {
                name: 'Facebook',
                data: [3, 4, 4, 2, 5]},
            {
                name: 'Yelp',
                data: [3, 4, 4, 2, 5]},
            {
                name: 'Google',
                data: [3, 4, 4, 2, 5]}]
        });
    });

});​​
</script>
<div id="container" style="min-width: 400px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

Comment: Have you tried specifying the full path name to the partial (i.e. `render 'admin/dashboard/graph'`)?

Comment: I just tried it, now I get this error = `Missing partial render admin/dashboard/graph with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :arb, :coffee]}`

Comment: I can get a dummy partial working, so I think the problem is with the actual partial code...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I fixed it, all I had to do was correctly reference my JavaScript with the `javascript_include` tags.

Comment: could you be more specific as to what you referenced in your javascript?

Answer (score 1):

Active admin doesn't seem to load any of your assets defined in application.js (or it doesn't seem to for me..). This caused an issue when I was trying to generate some charts.

I'm using raphael to create some charts. I have a folder within javascripts called raphael which contains all of my js files that I need.

So my partial looks like this:

_user_count.html.erb

```
<%= javascript_include_tag '/assets/raphael/raphael.js' %>
<%= javascript_include_tag '/assets/raphael/g.raphael.js' %>
<%= javascript_include_tag '/assets/raphael/g.pie.js' %>

<script>
  $(function() {
    var r = Raphael("holder"),
        pie = r.piechart(320, 240, 100, [55, 20, 13, 32, 5, 1, 2, 10], {
          legend: ["%%.%% - Enterprise Users", "%%.%% IE Users"], legendpos: "west", href: ["http://raphaeljs.com", "http://g.raphaeljs.com"]});

    r.text(320, 100, "Interactive Pie Chart").attr({ font: "20px sans-serif" });
    pie.hover(function () {
      this.sector.stop();
      this.sector.scale(1.1, 1.1, this.cx, this.cy);

      if (this.label) {
        this.label[0].stop();
        this.label[0].attr({ r: 7.5 });
        this.label[1].attr({ "font-weight": 800 });
      }
    }, function () {
      this.sector.animate({ transform: 's1 1 ' + this.cx + ' ' + this.cy }, 500, "bounce");

      if (this.label) {
        this.label[0].animate({ r: 5 }, 500, "bounce");
        this.label[1].attr({ "font-weight": 400 });
      }
    });
  });
</script>

<div id="holder"></div>
```

And my active admin section:

```
section "User Count", do
    div do
      render 'user_count'
    end
  end
```

Now you can use your JavaScript within the partial.

Answer (score 0):

In ActiveAdmin.setup do |config|
config.register_javascript 'http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js'